# Help identifying a connector where wires are directly inserted into "slots"

Tags: pcb-design, connector

My question is fairly simple.
Would you be able to identify this type of connector:
[image]

I can't seem to find it anywhere.It's not supposed to need any kind of crimp (wire is inserted inside as shown in the picture).

Comment: search for "insulation-displacement connector" type. A wire-insertion tool is recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this connector from TE Connectivity (p/n 3-643813-3): http://www.digikey.ca/products/en?keywords=3-643813-3-ND

The tool to punch the wires down (also from TE, p/n 59803-1) is this: http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/59803-1/A9982-ND/132430

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here, it would be good if you could edit this to include the actual manufacturer part (or better family) number and descriptive name, rather than just the digikey link and sales number.

Comment: Much thanks for sharing your knowledge on this. It is exactly what I was looking for.